# `sudo fbterm` returns "stdin isn't an interactive tty!"

Tags: command-line

I using Ubuntu 14.04

I installed `fbterm` using

```
sudo apt-get install fbterm
```

But when I type `sudo fbterm`

There is a message

```
stdin isn't a interactive tty!
```

Is that message an error? Or is something wrong?

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold

| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend

|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)

||/ Name                    Version          Architecture     Description
+                                                                           
ii  fbterm                  1.7-2            amd64       A fast framebuffer based terminal emulator for Linux
```

Comment: what does `which fbterm` say?

Comment: Fbterm (Frame buffer terminal emulator) is standalone replacement of Linux kernel terminal that can function outside of Xorg

Comment: Is that the responnse of `which fbterm`? Try runing it without `sudo`

Comment: I think fbterm is just a program, And I want to install on my server. but there is a message that is considered an error....

Comment: Yes I know that it is a program but was it installed correctly on your server, run `dpkg-query -l fbterm` put the result into your question

Comment: So Sorry. I put into it my questions.

Answer (score 0):

fbterm needs to be used without X.
Also as per the [manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/fbterm.1.html) the fbdev must be correctly configured/installed. Apart from this, it must be noted that fbterm works on tty only. if you want to try it out, logout of your ubuntu session and press CTRL+alt+F1(or F2 or F3) and login, and type fbterm.
(so as to get back to gdm/*dm login screen press CTRL+ALT+f6(or f7 or f8). There is also a way to replace the tty's with [fbterm](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=150473)

Answer (score 0):

This question is really old but i faced this problem earlier, found out to start fbterm you need to execute the following command

`exec fbterm`

Comment: fbterm often requires root privileges to access the framebuffer device, and running `exec fbterm` effectively places your entire terminal session under root access. This opens security vulnerabilities that could be exploited by malicious software.